# Model resource with users as FK TastyPie API

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

Using TastyPie I have a model resource which has a FK user. When I make a POST to the API I have to include the user id like this:

```
 data : JSON.stringify({ name : 'value a', user : '12' }),
```

My users have to authenticate either by logging in or using an API Key and username and password. In both cases **I already know who the user is**.

1) How can I make user sure that **user1** does not create a resource for **user2**?

2) or it is  counterintuitive to send the user ID at all? Should I somehow get the user from the authorization details, if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer question #1: The Tastypie documentation describes [how to create per-user resources](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources). Assuming that the user is already part of the request:

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'environment'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

    # Only allow creation of objects belonging to the user
    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        return super(EnvironmentResource, self).obj_create(bundle, user=bundle.request.user)

    # Only allow accessing resources for this user
    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```

To answer question #2, you should probably have the user be part of the session.

Comment: Shouldn't the first arg of super() in obj_create() be 'MyResource'?